# What is the right meaning of the sentence: "I should demonstrate restraint"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I've watched [this clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n5YD9_zkh3g) of The Originals TV show. Starting on **00:09** sec there's a dialog between Klaus and Elijah:

> Klaus: Finn and Kol must be turned to us.
>
> Elijah: ***I should demonstrate restraint***.

So what exactly does Elijah mean by saying that: that he doesn't want to do it, or he's saying that he disagree with Klaus, etc.??

Please, help me figure it out in the most accurate way possible.

Thanks, people :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"I should demonstrate restraint" means that Elijah may want to turn those people, but, for whatever reason, he knows he shouldn't. The use of "should" here tells me he's not saying that he doesn't agree with Klaus, just that he doesn't necessarily want to be a part of it.